# How to manually trigger routing on nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I want to navigate manually to home page after login in callback.

```
  methods: {
    async userLogin() {
      var session_url = "/api/v1/authenticate";
      axios
        .post(session_url, this.login, {})
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log("Authenticated", response.data.access_token);

          window.localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.access_token);
          // Manually trigger route here.
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Error on Authentication", error);
        });
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

To manually trigger route, you can use below code, where `/` is home route.

Note: No need to import anything as `$router` is globally available.

```
this.$router.push("/" )
```